# Are there any easter eggs in the Once Upon a Time TV show from the Lost TV show?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, lost

I have been watching Once upon a time recently, and am just starting the 4th season. I have noticed a number of easter eggs and references to the ABC series Lost. A few examples of these easter eggs so far are: the casting of at least 2 characters from Lost, a background ad for Hugo's favorite TV show, and a few others. I was wondering if there was a full list of Lost related easter eggs in once upon a time, or if I could get a few answers of things you found personally in the show? Episode numbers would be nice but are not necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the *[Once Upon a Time](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Los)* wiki:

### Season One

"Pilot"

Emma Swan is named, in part, after the Lost island's Swan Station. Her name is also derived from the story of "The Ugly Duckling".
Henry gets off the bus at Gate 4, the first of the Lost numbers.
There is a Geronimo Jackson sticker on Emma's car. Geronimo Jackson is a fictional band on Lost. The motif is from "Dharma Lady", a single by the fictional band.
The time on the clock tower in Storybrooke is frozen at 8:15. It is a reference to Oceanic Flight 815.
Regina and Henry live at house number 108, an important number on Lost, and the sum of the six recurring numbers.
There is a close-up of Emma's eye after she wakes up from the car crash.This is a recurring theme from Lost.
Henry's inbox contains e-mails from Mark, Daniel, Scott and Damon. The first three are all characters from Lost. "Damon" is a reference to Damon Lindelof, one of Lost's creators.
The clock unfroze at 8:15, then chimed at 8:16. 8, 15 and 16 are three of the Lost numbers.

"The Thing You Love Most"

The clock tower starts moving at 8:15, then chimes at 8:16, two of the Lost numbers.
The next morning, Regina sees the clock at 8:23. 23 is a reference Jack Shephard's number on Lost.
Emma's room number at the inn is 4. This is a reference to John Locke's number on Lost.

"Snow Falls"

During his date with Mary Margaret, Dr. Whale misunderstands and asks, "Something about you wanting 15 kids?" This is a reference to one of the Lost numbers.
A hospital sign reads "Critical Care Pharmacology 108". 108 is an important number on Lost, and the sum of the six recurring numbers.

"The Price of Gold"

Regina mentions that Emma lived in Tallahassee for two years, a reference to the episode "The Man From Tallahassee".

"That Still Small Voice"

Henry has Apollo bars in his backpack. This was a fictional candy bar on Lost.

"The Shepherd"

Emma and Mary Margaret share glasses of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey. This brand was featured on Lost.
David asks Mary Margaret to meet him by the Toll Bridge at 8 P.M.

"The Heart Is a Lonely Hunter"

When Emma walks away in anger, a pavement sign shows the number 15.
There is a close-up of Graham's eye as he awakens. This is a recurring theme from Lost.
Two darts at the sheriff's station are stuck in number 8 and 15, two of the Lost numbers.

"Desperate Souls"

When Emma is taking out her anger on the toaster, there is a bottle of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey on the countertop.

"True North"

Ava and Nicholas Zimmer hide stolen Apollo bars in Henry's bag.
The stranger's license plate features the number 23.

"7:15 A.M."

The voice of the Storybrooke meteorologist is one of Lost's creators, Damon Lindelof.
Mary Margaret is reading The Mysterious Island by Jules Verne in the diner. This is a reference to the main location on Lost, which is a mysterious island.
Mary Margaret is grabbing an Apollo bar off the store shelf when she bumps into Kathryn.
Snow White is sitting on a tree log with branches just like the one with Claire and Ethan sat on.

"Fruit of the Poisonous Tree"

A box from the Hall of Records is from aisle 08, section 4. 4 and 8 are two of the Lost numbers.
Regina's secret meeting in the woods takes place at Access Road 23. 23 is one of the Lost numbers.
Emma crashes her police cruiser into a street sign where the roads are numbered 4 and 23.
Emma's printout mentions the address "Dominion Street, Unit 4", a reference to the first Lost number.

"Skin Deep"

At The Rabbit Hole, as Ruby says, "Ash, check out those guys", a bottle of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey is sitting on a shelf behind the bar (only seen from a distance - it's at the top of the second shelf from the right).
The number 23 is on a door by the entrance to the psychiatric ward at the hospital.
The number 8 is on a door in the hallway inside the psychiatric ward.

"What Happened to Frederick"

The stranger says that his name is August. August is the 8th month of the year, and the second Lost number.
Regina tells Henry: "The occasion is I love you" when she gives him a present. Those same words are said by Penny to Desmond in Season 3.

"Dreamy"

Astrid tells Leroy that the nuns only sold 42 candles last year.
The phone record of Kathryn's call with David is listed as 8 minutes long (as Sidney points out).

"Red-Handed"

When Snow White and Red Riding Hood are looking for tracks in the woods, Red says that the one they're looking for will be, "Like, eight inches across". 8 is the second Lost number.
On Ruby's online list of potential jobs, there is a temporary position as an inventory control specialist for 8 months.
"Hat Trick"

Jefferson's house number is 316, a reference to Ajira Airways Flight 316.
At the market, when the Mad Hatter hears the price for the stuffed rabbit, he says he only has 8 coppers.

"The Return"

When August drives off on his motorcycle, a sign on the pavement shows the number 15.

"The Stranger"

The airplane Pinocchio is startled by has the Oceanic Airlines logo on it. Oceanic Airlines is the airline of the pivotal flight 815 on Lost.
Phuket, where August traveled to, is referred to on Lost, including the similarly named episode "Stranger in a Strange Land".
August woke up in Phuket at 8:15 A.M., two of the Lost numbers.

"An Apple Red as Blood"

In Regina's dream, Dopey wears a Geronimo Jackson T-shirt.

"A Land Without Magic"

As Emma dumps out Henry's backpack, an Apollo bar and a Geronimo Jackson audio cassette falls out.
The cover artwork on the cassette, is from "Dharma Lady", a single by the fictional band.
A sign next to the door that leads down to the psychiatric ward says "Critical Care Pharmacology 108". 108 is an important number on Lost, and the sum of the six recurring numbers.
The number 15 is on a pavement sign when David and Mary Margaret are reunited.
The clock tower stops at 8:15, the flight number from Lost.

### Season Two

"Broken"

As a mysterious man holds his iPod while struggling to close the apartment window, the back of the device's case is shown have a Geronimo Jackson logo. On Lost, Geronimo Jackson is a fictional band.
The Storybrooke clock tower shows 8:15, two of the Lost numbers.
The illustration of the clock tower on the postcard that the mysterious man receives, shows the same time.
Mary Margaret uses a bottle of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey to set fire to the railings. This is a fictional brand on Lost.

"We Are Both"

Dopey wears a Geronimo Jackson shirt. The motif is from "Dharma Lady", a single by the fictional band.

"The Doctor"

Henry Mills' horse is in stall 8, which is the second Lost number.

"Tallahassee"

Neal and Emma meet in Portland, a location referred to on Lost, and a reference to the episode "Not In Portland".
A Portland convenience store sells Apollo bars.
Neal and Emma plan to start a new life together in Tallahassee, a location referred to on Lost, and a reference to the episode "The Man From Tallahassee".
According to his wanted poster, Neal was born March 23, 1977. 23 is one of the Lost numbers, and 1977 was an important year in the Lost timeline.

"Child of the Moon"

When Granny is tracking Albert Spencer, a pavement sign shows the number 15.

"Queen of Hearts"

Dopey is wearing a Geronimo Jackson shirt.

"The Cricket Game"

The Evil Queen, upon being told the battle is lost, says, "Don't tell me what we can or cannot do!" This is a spin on the mantra often repeated by Locke on Lost.
At the party, Dopey is wearing a Geronimo Jackson shirt. Geronimo Jackson is a fictional band on Lost.
The number on a door in the corridor outside Archie's office is 4, the first Lost number.

"Tiny"

Exposé, a fictitious television series featured on Lost, is advertised on the television Belle is watching in the hospital as Ruby comes in to talk to her.
The announcer of the television just before Exposé returns from a commercial is one of Lost's creators, Damon Lindelof, reprising his vocal cameo of Bill Godwin.
Ruby gives Belle a copy of Jules Verne's The Mysterious Island. The main location of Lost is a mysterious island.
Dopey is wearing his Geronimo Jackson T-shirt.
When Mary Margaret and David walk away from the diner in the evening, a pavement sign shows the number 15.
Henry, Emma, and Mr. Gold take an Ajira Airlines flight, an airline that appears on Lost.
The total time of their flight is 42 minutes; a recurring number on Lost.

"Manhattan"

The number 23 can be seen in the bar where Neal and Emma are talking. 23 is the fifth of the Lost numbers.

"The Queen Is Dead"

According to the return address on the back of the envelope, Johanna's address is 42 Langdon Street. 42 is the sixth and final Lost number.

"Welcome to Storybrooke"

The newspaper Regina reads is dated October 23, 1983. 23 is one of the Lost numbers.
The clock tower is frozen at 8:15, two of the numbers from Lost.

"Selfless, Brave and True"

August wakes up in pain at 8:15 A.M, a reference to Oceanic Flight 815.

"The Evil Queen"

Neal and Tamara's room number at Granny's Bed and Breakfast is 8, the second Lost number.

"Second Star to the Right"

A bottle of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey is sitting on the table in the backroom of the pawnshop.
There is a close-up of Mary Margaret's eye as David drips Regina's tear into it.
When Baelfire and the Shadow fly past Big Ben, the clock reads 8:15 P.M.

"And Straight On 'Til Morning"

Mr. Gold pours himself and Belle a glass of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey.

### Season Three

"The Heart of the Truest Believer"

Henry Mills is born at 8:15; two of the Lost numbers, and the number of the Oceanic flight.

"Lost Girl"

Belle appearing to Rumple in Neverland could be an allusion to the Man in Black in lost.

"Good Form"

Regina offers Devin an Apollo bar.

"Dark Hollow"

Dopey wears a Geronimo Jackson shirt.
A bottle of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey is sitting on the table in the back room of the pawnshop.

"The New Neverland"

At the diner, Dopey wears a Geronimo Jackson shirt.

"Going Home"

At the town line, Dopey wears a Geronimo Jackson shirt.
The number 23 is seen over Emma's bed in the prison hospital. 23 is the fifth of the Lost numbers.
Emma's apartment alarm clock rings at 8:15 A.M. and stops at 8:15:04 A.M. 4, 8 and 15 are all Lost numbers.

"New York City Serenade"

Henry's off-screen babysitter is called Mrs. Cuse. Carlton Cuse was one of the show runners/executive producers of Lost.
Henry reaches level 23 while playing a video game. He also mentions reaching level 16. 16 and 23 are the fourth and fifth of the Lost numbers. (Level twenty-three is also a nod to the official Disney fan club D23.)
Emma buys Henry an Apollo candy bar at the drug store.
Henry informs Emma that Walsh will come over for a visit at 8 o'clock. 8 is the second Lost number.
When Emma arrives in Storybrooke, the clock tower shows the time as 8:15, two of the Lost numbers. The same time is on the clock in the Blanchard Loft.

"It's Not Easy Being Green"

Granny pours a customer a glass of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey.

"Kansas"

When David is talking to Emma at the hospital, the sign on the wall says "Suite 4". 4 is the first Lost number.
In Henry's newspaper, one of the classifieds shows the number 16, the fourth Lost number. Another ad contains the number 08. 8 is the second number from Lost.

"There's No Place Like Home"

The episode shares its name with the season finale of the fourth season of Lost.
Dopey is wearing a Geronimo Jackson shirt.

### Season Four

"A Tale of Two Sisters"

The episode's title is similar to the third season premiere of Lost, "A Tale of Two Cities" (named after the Charles Dickens novel of the same name), in which Lost and Once Upon a Time actress Elizabeth Mitchell made her first appearance.
A sign by the entrance to the psychiatric ward says "Critical Care Pharmacology 108". 108 is an important number on Lost, and the sum of the six recurring numbers.
Regina enters the code 815 when she enters the psychiatric ward, a reference to Oceanic Flight 815.

"White Out"

When Mary Margaret takes out her anger on her friends, she states that she's had eight hours of sleep in the last week, a reference to the second Lost number.

"The Apprentice"

When Will tries to break into the library, and when Belle finds him the next morning, he's holding a bottle of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey. This was a fictional brand featured on Lost.

"Family Business"

There is a close-up of Belle's eye as she awakens. This is a recurring theme from Lost.

"The Snow Queen"

Robin Hood's darts hit the wall near the numbers 8 and 15, two of the Lost numbers.

"Smash the Mirror"

The storybook page where young Regina is running away, and the page Robin Hood finds, are number XXIII (as Regina points out), a reference to the fifth Lost number, 23.
There is a close-up of Anna's eye as the shards from Ingrid's spell are absorbed into her body. This is a recurring theme from Lost.

"Fall"

After escaping Hans and his brothers, Anna says, "I don't hear eight enormous feet, so I think we lost them." This is a reference to the second Lost number.
There is a close-up of Mary Margaret's eye after the spell is enacted. This is a recurring theme from Lost.

"Shattered Sight"

In the first scene at the sheriff's station, the clock shows 8:15, a reference to the flight number from Lost.
Ingrid says to the foster children that light will be off in fifteen minutes, a reference to the third Lost number.
Ingrid tells young Emma that there are fifteen subconscious signs or tells that a new foster child displays when they're going to run away on their first night in a new home; a reference to Lost number 15.

"Darkness on the Edge of Town"

In the beginning of the episode, the hand on the town clock moves from 8:15 to 8:16. 8, 15 and 16 are three of the Lost numbers.
Cruella De Vil, Mr. Gold and Ursula go to a Mr. Cluck Chicken Shack restaurant, a famous fast food franchise in the show. Hugo, played by Once Upon a Time actor Jorge Garcia, previously worked for this fast food franchise, before becoming the owner in the flash-sideways world. It first appears in the episode "Everybody Hates Hugo", which was also written by Edward Kitsis and Adam Horowitz.
The drive-through worker is voiced by Daniel Dae Kim, who played Jin-Soo Kwon on ABC's Lost.
When Chernabog attacks, the number 15 is on a pavement sign outside the Marine Garage.

"Unforgiven

David pours himself a glass of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey, a fictional brand featured on Lost.

"Best Laid Plans"

There is a close-up of Snow White and Prince Charming's eye when the they touch the unicorn's horn. This is a recurring theme from Lost.

"Lily"

Emma and her foster family have takeout from Mr. Cluck Chicken Shack for dinner. This is a famous fast food franchise in the show.
There is a Geronimo Jackson patch on young Lily's hat. Geronimo Jackson is a fictional band on Lost.
The alias Lily had as an adult, Starla, references the Lost character of the same name, from the episode "Everybody Hates Hugo", which was written by Once Upon a Time creators Edward Kitsis and Adam Horowitz.

"Operation Mongoose Part 2"'

The song playing at Granny's Diner, "Shambala" by Three Dog Night, was also featured in the Lost episode "Tricia Tanaka Is Dead", which was also written by Edward Kitsis and Adam Horowitz.

### Season Five

"The Dark Swan"

Young Emma steals an Apollo bar from the movie goer's pocket.
Henry mentions that Regina uses his birthday for her passwords, including the one for the ward, and, since Regina enters '815' to get into the ward in A Tale of Two Sisters, his birthday is confirmed to be August 15, or 8/15, which is a reference to the first two Lost numbers.

"The Price"

Dopey is wearing a Geronimo Jackson T-shirt. This was a fictional band on Lost.

"The Bear and the Bow"

The number 8 is on a door in the hallway inside the psychiatric ward, a reference to the second number from Lost.
Merlin picks up an Apollo bar at Granny's Diner.

"Birth"

When Emma teleports Hook to the ground, the number 15 is on a pavement sign in front of Marine Garage, a reference to the third Lost number.

"Souls of the Departed"

The time on the broken clock tower in the Underworld is frozen at 8:15. It is a reference to Oceanic Flight 815.
The number on Neal's room key is 8, the second Lost number.
The clock tower unfreezes at 8:15, and moves to 8:16. 8, 15 and 16 are three of the Lost numbers.

"Labor of Love"

The clock tower is shown at 8:16, just like in the previous episode.

"Our Decay"

Zelena's birthday is April 15, or 4/15, two of the Lost numbers.

"Sisters"

The number 15 appears on a pavement sign outside the Underbrooke version of the Marine Garage; a reference to the third Lost number.

"Firebird"

The Cashier tells Emma that the diner can't keep a cook for six weeks. Six weeks are 42 days, the fifth Lost number.
Hades says that the portal to Storybrooke will stay open for "15 minutes tops", a reference to the third Lost number.
At the end of the episode, the hands on the clock tower spin around and stop at 8:15, then move to 8:16. 8, 15 and 16 are three of the Lost numbers.

"Only You"

The Toll Operator charges Mr. Gold 15 dollars, a reference to the third Lost number.
The number 15 appears on a sign outside Marine Garage in an establishing shot of Storybrooke.

### Season Six

"A Bitter Draught"

Dr. Hopper states that Bashful is his 4:00 appointment; a reference to Lost number 4.

"Strange Case"

In the title card, the time on the Big Ben is 8:15, a reference to Oceanic Flight 815 from Lost.

"Heartless"

There are close-ups of Hook's eyes as he studies the potion bottle. This is a common theme on Lost.
The Evil Queen asks Mary Margaret if she remembers her fifteenth birthday. The number 15 is a recurring Lost number.

### Once Upon a Time in Wonderland

"Down the Rabbit Hole"

The clock tower shows the time as 8:15, a reference to Oceanic flight 815.

### Bonus Features

"Tales From The Underworld: A Knight With Cruella"

When Cruella asks for a glass of whiskey, Mordred holds up an empty bottle of MacCutcheon Scotch Whiskey.

Comment: Full marks for comprehensiveness. Some of these may be stretching the point. For example, I agree that the clock stopping at 8.15 is a reference, but is the fact that it then moves to 8.16 additionally significant? What else was it going to move to?